# Where does "styling" code go in the MVC pattern?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

**B2:**

Please not the snippet below which sets styles to change in reaction to a user action -> i.e. blur, focus, keypress.

It is self contained...just give it an array of element ids and it sets the styles to change on certain events.

What module should I place this in Model, View, or Controller?

```
function styleTwitter1( pair_array )
{
    var i;
    var input;
    var label;
    for ( i = 0; i < pair_array.length; i+=2 ) 
    {
        input = document.getElementById( pair_array[ i ] );
        label = document.getElementById( pair_array[ i + 1 ] );
        label.style.fontSize = window.getComputedStyle( label, null ).getPropertyValue("font-size");
        closureBuster( input, label );
    }
    function closureBuster( input, label )
    {
        input.addEventListener( "keypress", function()
        { 
            label.style.opacity = 0; 
        }, false );
        input.addEventListener( "focus", function()
        { 
            if( input.value === '' )
            {
                label.style.opacity = 0.2; 
                input.style.border = '1px solid #888888'; 
            }
        } , false );
        input.addEventListener( "blur", function()
        {
            if( input.value === '' )
            {
                label.style.opacity = 1;
                new EffectsFont( label ).fade( 'up', 150 );
                input.style.border = '1px solid #dddddd'; 
            }   
        } , false );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVC the **view**:

> [observes the state and generates output to the users](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

So everything that the user sees (rendering, styling, ...) and interacts with, should go to the view.

Comment: The controller just initiates your interface, nothing else. What do you mean by "now I have to create another function or object"?

Answer (score 0):

**View** shows all you outputs to user, so anything that is relevant to visibility will be handled in view. So for best performance and results you should follow following steps

> Place your java script function in a separate js file
>   write a $(document).ready() function on top of each page (in   block) where you want to call required function and pass element array as parameters

in this way your code will be neat and clean, reusable and readable